# BeautifulSoup strips incomplete </tr> tags from html files

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to remove all script tags from html files using beautifulsoup. The problem is that html files do not have opening tags for table rows in some cases (there are only </ tr> tags at the end of the row) and beautifulsoup seems to be removing them, since they are incomplete. This messes up the formatting of the table as a result. Is there any other way to remove these script tags without messing up the formatting?

```
import os 
from pathlib import Path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root_dir = os.path.join(Path().absolute(),'newfolder\\')
for path in Path(root_dir).iterdir():
    if path.is.file():
        htmlfile = open(path,encoding="utf-8".read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)
        to_be_removed = soup.find_all("script")
        for x in to_be_removed:
            x.extract()
        html = soup.prettify("utf-8")

        with open(path,"wb") as file:
            file.write(html)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to the parser used by BeautifulSoup to read your HTML document, at `soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)`.

BeautifulSoup uses `lxml` as the default, which makes assumptions such as that your HTML is valid. When that is not the case, I would suggest looking into a more lenient parser - the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) is a great source of information for this.

To get specific, you could use `html.parser` as it's more lenient, and finally try outputting your code without prettifying it, by using:

```py
html = soup.prettify(formatter=None)
```